# Magento admin url - remove index.php (Godaddy Server)

Tags: magento-1.7

Magento installed on WAMP and working fine.

SITE URL = localhost/shop <-||->
ADMIN URL = localhost/shop/index.php/admin

I moved this magento to Godaddy server. It is NOT in the root folder. The site is in a sub folder named “shop”

SITE URL = mydomain.com/shop <-||-> 
ADMIN URL = mydomain.com/shop/index.php/admin

Front-end url is working fine - mydomain.com/shop/customer/account/login/

Admin url is not working with “index.php” included. When I remove “index.php” and call the url manually then it is working.

I want my admin url as http://mydomain.com/shop/admin/system_config/edit/....

### MY CONFIGURATION

Use Web Server Rewrites = Yes

### IN .HTACCESS

RewriteBase /shop/

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution can be found here:
[How to remove index.php from admin URL](http://www.code007.ro/magento-how-to-remove-index-php-from-admin-url/)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the index.php from Magento admin URL add the following code on the top of the /shop/index.php file in Magento folder:

```
<?php
    function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
    $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
    }

    $curUrl = curPageURL();
    $pos = strpos($curUrl, "index.php");

    // Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
    // because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
    if ($pos === false) {
    //echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
    } else {
    //echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    //echo " and exists at position $pos";
    $newUrl = str_replace("index.php/", "", $curUrl);
    header("Location: $newUrl");
    exit;
    }
?>
```

Enjoy :)